# Strange behavior onBackPressed

Tags: android, onbackpressed

I have an activity contains WebView and I'm passing URL while opening,
Like this:

```
Intent activity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NewActivity.class);
activity.putExtra("URL", url);
startActivity(activity);
```

When we press back button it closes all previous activities and return to MainActivity so I overrided `onBackPressed.`

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
    }
```

and it still close all previous activities.

**Note :** It declared in manifest like this:

```
<activity
            android:name=".views.activities.NewActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

What is the wrong with it?

**How can i fix this,** I just want to open previous activity `onBackPressed` and finish current one.

Comment: Have you tried `Intent activity = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class);`?  Try with `CurrentActivity.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: Do you call `finish()` on your first activity after starting the `NewActivity`?

Comment: Sorry but using CurrentActivity.this instead of getApplicationContext() didn't work for me

Comment: You open NewActivity in MainActivity?

Comment: I'm sure I didn't call finish() on first activity

Comment: After MainActivity I navigate to another 2 activities before I open NewActivity

Comment: add please code opening of these activities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understood correctly you want to navigate to previously loaded webpages in your `WebView` rather than closing it from current page.

if that's true try this solution.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed(); // or finish();  
    }
}
```

Comment: No I don't, I want to navigate to previous activity but what happens actually is that pressing back button close all previous activities and return to MainActivity

Comment: from which activity are you calling webview?

Comment: I'm calling WebView inside NewActivity

Answer (score 0):

Try to exit view.

```
@Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
 System.exit(REQUEST_CODE);
 super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Same problem and same behavior